# LaTeX-environment inserts unwanted empty line

Tags: latex, tex

When I'm editing a LaTeX document and I'm using `C-c C-e` for `LaTeX-environment`, I often get a blank line after the newly-inserted environment.  This is never what I want and sometimes even plainly wrong because it can lead to errors if you for example insert a matrix into a displayed equation.

Is there an easy way to turn this off?  I checked the customization options but couldn't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following lisp code.

Put it into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and restart emacs.

The function `auctex+-insert-environment-avoid-empty-line` kills the emtpy line after `\end{...}` if there is one.

```el
(defun auctex+-insert-environment-avoid-empty-line (_name _start end)
  "Avoid insertion of empty line after environment."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char end)
    (when (and (eq 0 (forward-line))
               (looking-at "[[:space:]]*$"))
      (kill-line))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-after-insert-env-hook #'auctex+-insert-environment-avoid-empty-line)
```

Tested with
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.28) of 2018-05-28
and auctex 11.92.0.

I've got it running for a while now and it does what I want.